# No reponse while sendind form data from angular js to mysql db using spring

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring

HI all i am new to angular and i am trying to learn it. i have developed an app that takes input data from angular and validations done and post the data to my server using spring as controller.

my controller class

```
@Autowired
UserRegistrationDao userDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("userReg") UserRegistration userReg) {
    System.out.println("hi");
    userDao.registerUser(userReg);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.jsp");
}
```

my sample.js

```
    var app = angular.module('ngMailChimp', []);

app.controller('SignUpController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.list = [];
        $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
        $scope.submit = function() {

            var formData = {
                    "firstName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.firstName,
                    "lastName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.lastName,
                    "streetName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.streetName,
                    "aptName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.aptName,
                    "cityName" : $scopectrl.newCustomer.cityName,
                    "stateName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.stateName,
                    "countryName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.countryName,
                    "zipName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.zipName,
                    "userName" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.userName,
                    "password" : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.password,
            };

            var response = $http.post('save', formData);
            response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.list.push(data);
            });
            response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
            });

            $scope.list = [];

        };
    }]);
```

my sample.jsp

```
<body  ng-app="ngMailChimp" ng-controller="SignUpController as ctrl">
    <div class="signup-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="resources/assets/images/Untitled.png" alt="Logo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-success message-animation" role="alert" ng-if="ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt">
            Thank you! Your account has been created.
        </div>
        <form name="ctrl.signupForm" ng-submit="submit()">/*ctrl.signup()*/

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('firstName')}">
                <label for="firstName"><strong>First Name</strong></label>
                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" required
                       ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.firstName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                       ng-focus="ctrl.toggleFirstNamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="ctrl.toggleFirstNamePrompt(false)"/>

                <div class="my-messages">
                    <div class="prompt message-animation" ng-if="ctrl.showFirstNamePrompt">
                        Please Enter your First Name.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="ctrl.signupForm.firstName.$error" ng-if="ctrl.showMessages('firstName')">
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="required">
                        This field is required.<br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('lastName')}">
                <br><label for="lastName"><strong>Last Name</strong></label>
                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" required
                       ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.lastName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                       ng-focus="ctrl.toggleLastNamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="ctrl.toggleLastNamePrompt(false)"/>

                <div class="my-messages">
                    <div class="prompt message-animation" ng-if="ctrl.showLastNamePrompt">
                        Please Enter your Last Name.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="my-messages" ng-messages="ctrl.signupForm.lastName.$error" ng-if="ctrl.showMessages('lastName')">
                    <div class="message-animation" ng-message="required">
                        This field is required.<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create My Account</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

we-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.weber.xxx.controller"></context:component-scan>


<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ds"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/weber" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao"
    class="org.weber.xxx.user.registration.dao.UserRegistrationDaoImpl">
    <property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>weber</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/weber-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>weber</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Its not even hitting my spring controller.Where am i going worng.please help me out

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not hitting your controller, obviously your form is not being submitted.

I'm not familiar with AngularJS, but from looking at your JSP file, you're missing a couple of attributes within the form tag:

1. action=the_url_of_your_controller
2. method=POST

Like this:

```
<form action="the_url_of_your_controller" method="POST">
```

If this next line:

```
var response = $http.post('save', formData);
```

is responsible for posting your form with AngularJS, then you need to add a full web server address, let's say something like this:

```
var response = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/your_webapp_name/save', formData);
```

Comment: That works for the servlet use but  i want to route the request to my spring controller

Comment: What I suggested above works perfectly fine on spring controllers. if you want a better approach resolving URLs to your spring controllers, try to use spring:url tag, you'll need to import the appropriate taglib.

Comment: I think angular directly gives the objects for us.I tried the above but again i have to create the objects for it in spring/servlet.I am trying to use it with scope.

Comment: I improved my answer, try what i wrote inside your js file

Comment: No luck its not hitting the controller.

Comment: It worked out with the full url plus i had made some changes in servlet.xml by adding "<mvc:annotation-driven />".Thank you.